# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Ajax post is null using FromBody

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages, frombodyattribute

I'm developing an ASP.NET (6.0) Razor Pages application. One of the pages needs to post data using AJAX, however, the post is always null.

I have tried to use the previous related questions to this on Stack Overflow, but my problem still persists.

**This is my Razor Page (cshtml)**

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('button').on('click', function(){

const token = $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var data = { "MyVar": "Simon", "MyNum": 21 };

$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=SaveOrder',
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken" : token
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
</script>
```

**This is my PageModel for the same Razor Page**

[image]

As you can see, the Ajax Post is working in that it hits the appropriate handler method, but no data is posted.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: @PoulBak Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but that amendment doesn't work either. Now I don't even seen the model properties when posted, i.e. MyNum and MyVar.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Converting a comment (which OP verified as the solution in a follow-up comment) to an answer:</sup>

> Just noticed: The properties of `SectionInputModel` must be `public` to support model binding.
> – [Poul Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741643/poul-bak)  [Oct 21, 2022 at 12:37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74153217/asp-net-core-razor-pages-ajax-post-is-null-using-frombody#comment130923602_74153217)